# How to correctly use setDate?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, getdate

I have table with column "date" and type Date in format: "2011-09-06"
and i want to execute query:

```
select * from tvprograms where date=?
```

And I try this:

```
Date startDate;
java.util.Date date;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 9, 1);
startDate = cal.getTime();
TVProgramDAO tvDAO = new TVProgramDAO();
tvDAO.findUnusedTvPrograms(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

findUnusedTvPrograms looks:

```
public List<Integer> findUnusedTvPrograms(Date date) {
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (obtainConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ...
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(findOldTvProgQuery.toString());

            stmt.setDate(1, date);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                results.add(rs.getInt(1));
             ...
    return results;
}
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: Watch out with month numbers in `Calendar.set(...)`, these are 0-based in Java, so month 9 = October, not September as you might expect. Use the constants instead of numbers, for example `Calendar.SEPTEMBER`.

Answer (score 2):

This code won't compile to start with as far as I can see:

```
Date startDate;
java.util.Date date;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 9, 1);
startDate = cal.getTime();
TVProgramDAO tvDAO = new TVProgramDAO();
tvDAO.findUnusedTvPrograms(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

You're trying to use `date` but you've never initialized the variable. Here's a slightly cleaner version:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 9, 1);
Date startDate = cal.getTime();
TVProgramDAO tvDAO = new TVProgramDAO();
tvDAO.findUnusedTvPrograms(new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
```

Note that that will use the default time zone of the system, which may not be a good idea. Personally I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead...